# PHP: Call abstract class method in another class

Tags: php, oop

I hope to be very clear!

I have [dbFacile](https://github.com/alanszlosek/dbFacile) class who fetch, insert and work with my DB.

```
$db = dbFacile::open( 'mysql', DATABASE, USERNAME, PASSWORD, HOST );

$db->fetchRows('select * from my_stores')
```

I've created another class where i want to get an $array with all of my stores from table my_stores.

```
class Stores {
    public $s_table = 'my_stores';
    public $rows;
    public function get_all_stores (){      
        $this->rows = $db->fetchRows('select * from $this->s_table');
        foreach($rows as $row) {
            echo $row['name'] . '<br />';
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried to initiate dbFacile in my **get_all_stores** method but that class is abstract and i can't.

Comment: shouldn't you use one of the factory methods (like `\dbFacile\factory::mysqli()`)?

Comment: I will but i dont know how i cand use something like this, i dont have that factory file online db.class.php

Comment: @radmen can you help me here: http://collabedit.com/fpee7 ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand where do you have problem. The file you posted on collabedit is different than the one posted in question. The only problem in first file is that you forgot to pass `$db` to `Stores` constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you want to do it is to inject `$db` in the `Stores` class via its constructor

```
class Stores {
  private $db;
  public function __construct(className $db) {
    $this->db = $db;
  }
}
```

where className should be the full namespace class name of dbFacile base class. So that PHP throws an error whenever you try to instantiate Stores with the wrong dependency.

This way you're injecting your dependency in the Stores class and you can use $this->db wherever you want inside that class.

Comment: What means dbFacile base class? Can you help me here: http://collabedit.com/fpee7 ?

Answer (score 1):

From it's unit tests folder of the github repository you can see the new intended usage is:

```
$db = \dbFacile\factory::mysql();
$db->open(DATABASE, USERNAME, PASSWORD, HOST);
$db->fetchRows('select * from my_stores');
...
```

An example using your class:

```
class Stores {
private $s_table = 'my_stores';
private $db;

public function __construct($db)
{
    $this->db = $db;
}

public function get_all_stores (){
    $rows = $this->db->fetchRows(sprintf('select * from %s', $this->s_table));
    //do your stuff with rows and maby return $rows 
 }
}

$db = \dbFacile\factory::mysql();
$db->open(DATABASE, USERNAME, PASSWORD, HOST);

//usage
$stores = new Stores($db);
$stores->get_all_stores();
```

Comment: How i can use this in my new class ?

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method dbFacile_mysql::fetchRows()

Comment: How did you include the library ?

Answer (score 0):

You could pass db object into Stores via constructor. Read about dependency injection.